# Custom directive is overriding scope

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a custom directive as defined below (if you need controller let me know)

```
module.exports = angular.module('aah-yes-no-directive-module', [
  require('./yes-no.controller').name,
]).directive('aahYesNo', [function YesNoDirective() {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'partials/yes-no.template.html',
    require: ['aahYesNo', 'ngModel'],
    controller: 'aahYesNoController',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    link: (scope, el, attrs, ctrls) => {
      let ctrl = ctrls[0],
        ngModelCtrl = ctrls[1];

      ctrl.init(ngModelCtrl, attrs.onValue, attrs.offValue);

      angular.element(el).children().addClass(attrs.size || '');
    },
    scope: {}
  };
}]);
```

Why question is, why does it not update the `$modelValue` when it changes in the parent controller, or when `$viewValue` changes?

it is always `undefined`?

if i take out `scope: {}` it works, but seems to override the entire parent scope (?!)

Answer (score 1):

Because `scope: {}` creates an isolated scope,

You can tell directive to inherit parent scope by setting `scope: true` or by not defining scope property.

Check [this article](https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/) for more details about scope in directives

Answer (score 0):

I have it working, I'm not sure exactly what I changed to fix it, but unfortunately wasn't either of the suggested reasons.

It was not working properly with `scope: false`, I suspect I had a typo somewhere and have ended up starting again and voila....thanks for the help though!